# Execute page show and leave animations: transitions only fire occasionally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I execute animations upon navigating (via $router) to and from a page/url. Ie, how can I perform animations on show and on leave of a page? I will have different enter and leave animations for each page. The animations are complex thus we use javascript callbacks instead of css3 implementation

I have attempted the following but the transition callbacks dont fire every time. For some pages the callbacks fire for others they dont and they all have the exact code. It's quite weird.

Example `MyPage.vue` (could be `Contact.vue`, `AboutUs.vue` etc.):

```
<template>
  <transition v-on:enter="enter" v-on:leave="leave">
      <main>
        <p>Foo</p>
      </main>
  </transition>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

import gsap from 'gsap' // include animation library

export default { 
  methods: {
      enter: function (el, done) {

        // I only see the text enter sometimes for a page. Its not consistently firing
        console.log('enter')
        done()
      },

      leave: function (el, done) {
        // I only see the text leave sometimes for a page. Its not consistently firing
        console.log('leave')
        done()
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example : https://codesandbox.io/s/n38vz0pnzp

It's triggering as expected.

I added the `appear` prop which triggers the enter animation even for the first component mounting (when starting the app).